# multiple themes to choose in css

Tags: javascript, css

User picks two colors - background and text. When user press 'apply' div changes. But I want the themes to be seperate, like two themes are working at once: one for background, second for text. So there's 4 themes options and 2 of them must be selected. But only one at the time is applied!
I know this explanation is blurry so please check the example on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7Lysdwzo/2/
try it and then comment the second line in function saveTheme: setTheme(theme2);
. Only one aspect changes every time.

code:

```
<div>
<div id="choose"></div>

  <div class="toggle-container">
    <button onclick="theme1='light';showChosen()" title="Light mode">
     light
    </button>
    <button onclick="theme1='dark';showChosen()" title="Dark mode">
     dark
    </button>
    <br/>
    <button onclick="theme2='Blue';showChosen()" title="Blue">
     Blue
    </button>
    <button onclick="theme2='Green';showChosen()" title="Green">
     Green
    </button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="div1" style="height:100px;width:100px"> div </div>
  
</div>

:root,
:root.light {
  --bg-color: #fff;
}
:root.dark {
  --bg-color: #121212;
  
}
button:checked {
  border:1px solid red;
}

:root,
:root.Blue {
  --text-color: blue;
}

:root.Green {
  --text-color: green;
}

.div1,.div2 {
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  color: var(--text-color)
}
const setTheme = theme => document.documentElement.className = theme;

var theme1="";
var theme2="";

function saveTheme() {
setTheme(theme1);
setTheme(theme2);

}

function showChosen() {
var str = 'background should be: ' + theme1 + ';;; text should be: ' + theme2 + '<button onclick="saveTheme()" title="Green"> apply</button>';
document.getElementById("choose").innerHTML = str;

}
```

Is there a way to use two themes at once, one for one aspect, and the other for other aspect?

Comment: By not rewriting the class attribute?

Comment: @gre_gor i tried but failed, I dont have any idea how to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use classList.add and classList.remove instead of replacing the whole className.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wgcvt243/1/)

```
const setTheme = theme => document.documentElement.classList.add(theme);

var theme1="";
var theme2="";

function saveTheme() {
  // remove all the themes that the user could have added before
  document.documentElement.classList.remove("light", "dark", "Blue", "Green");
  setTheme(theme1);
  setTheme(theme2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use classes. You can use data-attributes to store each type and just use a single event handler to look for the class to determine what to do.

```js
function setTheme(el,theme,type){
   el.setAttribute("data-" + type,theme);
}

let target = document.querySelector(".div1");

document.body.addEventListener("click",function(e){
   let btn = e.target;
   if(btn.classList.contains("setTheme")){
     target.setAttribute("data-" + btn.dataset.type,btn.dataset.theme);
     
    var str = 'background should be: ' + (target.dataset.bg || "") + ';;; text should be: ' + (target.dataset.text || "") + '<button class="saveTheme" title="Green"> apply</button>';
    document.getElementById("choose").innerHTML = str;
   }
   else if(btn.classList.contains("saveTheme")){
      console.log("save")
   }
});
```

```css
:root,
[data-bg="theme1"] {
  --bg-color: #fff;
}
[data-bg="theme2"] {
  --bg-color: #121212;
  
}
button:checked {
  border:1px solid red;
}

:root,
[data-text="blue"]{
  --text-color: blue;
}

[data-text="green"]{
  --text-color: green;
}

.div1,.div2 {
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  color: var(--text-color)
}
```

```html
<div>
<div id="choose"></div>

  <div class="toggle-container">
    <button class="setTheme" data-type="bg" data-theme="theme1" title="Light mode">
     light
    </button>
    <button class="setTheme" data-type="bg" data-theme="theme2" title="Dark mode">
     dark
    </button>
    <br/>
    <button class="setTheme" data-type="text" data-theme="blue" title="Blue">
     Blue
    </button>
    <button class="setTheme" data-type="text" data-theme="green" title="Green">
     Green
    </button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="div1" style="height:100px;width:100px"> div </div>
  
</div>
```